# Should I dispose jface CellEditors returned from EditorSupport

Tags: java, memory-leaks, swt, jface

Should I dispose `CellEditor` returned from `EditingSupport.getCellEditor`, and if so when should I do it.

On one of the tutorials on jface `TableViewer` I saw following snippet:

```
public class FirstNameEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        return new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());
    }
```

so would this method leak memory if cell was edited multiple times? Or should I just lazy initialize `CellEditor`:

```
 public class FirstNameEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {

    CellEditor editor;

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        if(editor == null){
           editor = new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());
       }

       return editor;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet looks like a nasty leak to me if you use such a `EditingSupport` for `ViewerColumns`. Just have a look at the source of [ColumnViewerEditor](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#9oBwOhrJiYY/src/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnViewerEditor.java&q=ColumnViewerEditor&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc), the class handling lots of the work around `CellEditors`. There are lots of lines like

```
if(part.getEditingSupport() != null)
```

(with `part` being a `ViewerColumn`). These calls create a `Text` instance in the constructor of the `TextCellEditor`. But since the `EditingSupport` instance is not assigned, it will be GCed immediately. The `Text` instance will not be disposed (until its parent is disposed). Leak.

So your second snippet seems way better.

Which tutorial? Maybe you should report that.